# asp.net core mvc 2.0 logging with IIS

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC Core 2.0 web application.

I am sending log informations with ILogger.

Here is my main Program class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
               logging.AddConsole();
               logging.AddDebug();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

My application is hosted on a Windows/IIS Server.
Where does the log is written ?

I have checked in %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles folder.

I can see some subfolders with a log file which contains an entry for each hit but i do not see any entry for my log messages.

Thanks